# Read skype message archive

Tags: message, archive, skype

I would like to read my skype message archive outside of the Skype app. And be able to export it in some sort (other than copy-paste it from my messages) as far i can figure skype only provides 30 days or archives.

Any one out there using an app for archiving / exporting Skype messages?

Comment: This is a handy little utility that allows for parsing the history files (of Skype on all platforms - the actual program however only runs on Windows): * [LogView Official Homepage](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html)

Comment: You may find this Skype add-on helpful: http://scand.com/products/skyhistory/index.html.
It helps saving and storing Skype chat history on a separate flash drive, and it is free.

Comment: I found the software <a href="http://skypelogr.com/">SkypeLogR</a> extremely useful if one wants to quickly export all chat logs into text files. It will do that for all accounts available on the host machine. Doesn't require Skype password.

Comment: There is now a web service for viewing and exporting Skype main.db files: [skypebrowser.com](http://www.skypebrowser.com)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also look at skype's profile database (**%USERDIR%\Application Data\Skype\%your profile name%\main.db**) which is basically SQLite database and see what you can get from it. If you are using **Windows 8 and above** the path is **%USERDIR%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp\Localstate\ %your_skype_profile_name%\main.db**

I'll give you a hit about tables:

- "Conversations" - a conversation
- "Messages" linked to "Conversations" via convo_id field
- "Chats" - a list of saved chats, each chat is composed of conversations
- "ChatMembers" - members of chat(s)

The tables are quite wide and usage of some fields is not that obvious, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 15):

C'mon now, this is Stackoverflow, let's get technical, shall we? Let's put away childish jpegs, gui tools, and spreadsheet psuedocode and get to the heart of the problem!

*[fist bump]*

Source: https://coolaj86.com/articles/searching-skypes-sqlite-database/

## Find your Skype DB

First you've got to find the correct skype db for your user:

```
ls ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/

sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/<<YOUR_USER_NAME>>/main.db
```

## Learn them Tables Good!

You'll want to take a look at the available tables, and their descriptions:

```
.tables          " see the short table list
.schema Contacts " all about the Contacts table
.schema Messages " all about the Messages table
```

You'll probably need to use the good ol' `ctrl+f` to search in the output for things like `time`, `author`, and `username`.

## Dive into the SQLs

Then you gotsta dive into the SQLs...

```
" List the 25 most recently contacted contacts
SELECT skypename, lastused_timestamp FROM Contacts ORDER BY lastused_timestamp DESC LIMIT 25;

" List the 100 most recent messages
SELECT id, convo_id, timestamp, type, author, body_xml FROM Messages ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;

" List the 100 most recent conversations (and all participants)
SELECT last_activity_timestamp, identity, type, given_displayname, displayname FROM Conversations ORDER BY last_activity_timestamp DESC LIMIT 100;

" Search for a message with the text 'home'
SELECT author, body_xml FROM Messages WHERE body_xml LIKE '%HOME%' ORDER BY timestamp ASC;

" Search for a contact named 'john'
SELECT (displayname || ' : ' || skypename || ' : ' || fullname) as names FROM Contacts WHERE names LIKE '%JOHN%' ORDER BY lastused_timestamp ASC;
```

(note comments are with a ", not a #)

Note that

- `Messages` refers to a line of text such as "What's up?"
- `Conversations` refers to a collection of Messages between 2 or more parties.
- I think `Chats` refers to the logical time gaps separated with labels like 'yesterday', '7 days ago', 'March 24th', etc

Answer (score 7):

**I recommend two ways to do this:**

A. **Easiest way is to use [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/)**. Available for Windows, Linux and Mac. You can do all this

[image]

This is the search function:

[image]

And here is sample output from an export:

[image]

B. **The harder, but naturally more flexible way, is to install a SQLite Browser**, such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/), and export the messages yourself. You can see some information on how to do that by looking at [this article](http://stephanietan.boldersecurity.com/2011/04/analyzing-skype-chat-and-call-logs.html), or you could also search for other similar articles ([AlexS' answer also provides clues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941233/139040)). You will need some experience with SQL to use this option.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out: http://web.archive.org/web/20061019071406/https://developer.skype.com/Docs/ApiDoc/CHAT_object

```
CHATMESSAGES - list of chatmessage identifiers 
CHATMESSAGES - all messages IDs in this chat, for example CHAT #test_l/$6a072ce5537c4044 CHATMESSAGES 34, 35, 36, 38, 39
```

Comment: That link is broken.  Does Skype still have an API?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Skype history,
Every body is looking to play around these history for many reasons.
I would like to share my experience with you, since I'm not expert but this may help somebody.

Whether you have desktop or smart device, Main.db file is the core of the skype History, it's SqL 3 file.

How to get it?????????????????

**1. Desktop:**

1. close the Skype and Find the file Main.db at `C:/Users/[your computer username]/App Data/Roaming/Skype/[your Skype Id]` (please review this for Win7, and for XP and others you have to find the file).
2. Make backup for this file at other drive.
3. use any sql software like SQLite or SQLite Expert or other to open the file as database.
4. at the Data menu you can see all your information for the history in the left of the program like messages, calls, conversations, and so many details.
5. you will find the outgoing and incoming IM message in messages.
6. click right and go to select column and select the columns of interest like ID user name body-xml for the message text and timestamp.
7. you can shorten your selection with tick the required fields.
8. Click right and select text edit and then you can do whatever you need, add delete, etc. for the selected field.
9. you don't need to save anything because it's automatically saved.
10. very important for time step that it uses different kind of date format, for example you find the timestamp 1261610607 for the date time 23/12/2009 18:23,

    **so how can you adjust the time?**

    you can simply open an Excel sheet and paste the equation:

    `=IF(H6="","",(H6/86400)+25569+(-5/24))`

    and that's all.
11. Now reopen it again then, see the history of the chat.

**2. For Smart devices (Ipad as example):(you have to use desktop or laptop for assistance:**

1. Download and install iExplorer for iPad or some other browsing software.
2. Connect your device and you will see most of your files.
3. Select `APPs/Skype/Library/App Support/Skype/[your Skype ID]`.
4. Send the file to your desktop by click right and export file.
5. repeat the steps as shown above from 2 - 11 like for Desktop procedures.
6. After finishing the editing close the database and from iExplorer point to your Skype user and select `Add File`, browse to the modified file and send it again to the iPad.
7. Start Skype and see the results.

Comment: Years later and I'm struggling with this exact issue (the timestamps being in a strange format).  Unfortunately for me though, your provided formula in Excel always gives a result of `10/31/13 13:09` regardless of what the incoming timestamp is.