# How to access the Skype API without wrappers?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, skype, skype4com

I need to write a Webpart (in Sharepoint 2010) which should be able to read the chat history in Skype. To achieve this goal I have to use the Skype API. All tutorials that I've seen use wrappers.

Question: How can I access the Skype API without wrappers?

Comment: Don't know if using API, but there is a local sqlite database file, which contains some data, even chat history.

Comment: I know about local files, but I need API instead

Comment: Please look at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859077/read-skype-message-archive for answer.

Thanks

Comment: Developer Jigar Pandya, saw that question, it doesn't solve my problem :)

Comment: Did you atleast RTFM for skype API?

Comment: yes) I did. SKYPE4COMLib also doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interact with skype API I have to use [SKYPE4COM](http://developer.skype.com/accessories/skype4com), but skype client should be launched to make your code work.

Answer (score 2):

what about accessing skype db like in this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941233/880434

---

*EDIT*

**SKYPE4COMLib** will help you to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my web part I don't have access to the local machine and get main.db file because of this I am considering to get history using API. 

P.S. Second your link doesn't work