# How to read all Skype contacts and messages without using Skype API?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, api, skype

I need to find a way to read all contacts and chat messages from Skype without API.

By Microsoft they will not support the Skype API any more. This is why I need it.
In the C:\Documents and Settings**username**\Application Data\Skype there are some files but need to parse them and not sure how if it is the right approach.

Of course the chat messages are always synchronized from the cloud. I need at least the messages saved on the disk.

Comment: they are stored in sqlite database. You need to read that database `main.db` [Using Sqlite with C#](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/#/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Ilya Ivaonv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1283124/ilya-ivanov) Skype saves all the data in the SQLLite main.db file situated in **%AppData%\Skype**  folder.

Answer (score 1):

**I recommend two ways to do this:**

A. **Easiest way is to use [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.io/Skyperious/)**. Available for Windows, Linux and Mac. You can do all this

[image]

This is the search function:

[image]

And here is sample output from an export:

[image]

B. **The harder, but naturally more flexible way, is to install a SQLite Browser**, such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/), and export the messages yourself. You can see some information on how to do that by looking at [this article](http://stephanietan.boldersecurity.com/2011/04/analyzing-skype-chat-and-call-logs.html), or you could also search for other similar articles ([AlexS' answer also provides clues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941233/139040)). You will need some experience with SQL to use this option.