# Access Skype via Programming Language

Tags: java, c++, api, go, skype

I am proficient in many programming languages, so I do not mind where you point me.

I would like to be able to grab the data from a specific Skype conversation's topic.

Is there an easy way to do this an any programming language?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859077/read-skype-message-archive

Answer (score 0):

Try Skype APIs for Java.

[http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20(English)](http://skype.sourceforge.jp/index.php?Skype%20API%20For%20Java%20%28English%29)
and
https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api